How to Differentiate Between Navigation Route Change and Initial Load in Next.js 14?
I'm currently working with Next.js 14 and its App Router paradigm to manage navigation within my application. I have implemented a background color transition on certain pages that is triggered when navigating between routes. However, I want this transition to occur only on route changes, not when the page is accessed directly by typing the URL into the browser.
Problem: My layout includes a CSS transition effect for the background color that I only want to trigger when users navigate to specific pages from other parts of the app (not on initial page loads).
Question: Is there a way in Next.js 14 to detect if a page load is the result of a navigation route change versus an initial direct access? I need this to conditionally apply the background color transition.
Any guidance or suggestions on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!
I attempted to adjust my layout.tsx to make it a client component, thinking it might help differentiate between navigation changes and direct loads. However, this approach did not resolve the issue as it didn't logically fit the requirements.

Using Router.events to track route changes
You can use Router.events from the next/router package to track route changes in Next.js. The main idea is to set a flag after the initial page load and then listen to route change events to detect client-side navigations.
    import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isInitialLoad, setIsInitialLoad] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs only on the initial load
    if (isInitialLoad) {
      console.log("Initial load");
      setIsInitialLoad(false); // Set flag to false after the first render
    }

    const handleRouteChange = (url) => {
      console.log("Client-side route change to:", url);
    };

    // Listen for route changes
    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleRouteChange);

    // Cleanup the event listener
    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeStart', handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, [isInitialLoad, router.events]);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
};

export default MyApp;

Alternative: Using a Global State or Context
You can also track the initial load and client-side navigations by keeping a global state (using useContext or other state management tools like Redux). This might be more useful in a larger app.

To solve this you can use a custom hook to detect route changes, then a wrapper component to use it wherever we want :


import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';

export function useIsFirstMount() {
  const isFirst = useRef(true);
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirst.current) {
      isFirst.current = false;
      return;
    }
    // This will run on route changes, but not on the initial mount as you wanted
    console.log('Route changed');
  }, [pathname, searchParams]);

  return isFirst.current;
}



Then create a client-side component wrapper that uses this hook (After that we can use this wrapper to wrap any component and apply this styling logic):


'use client';

import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { useIsFirstMount } from './useIsFirstMount';

interface TransitionWrapperProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export function TransitionWrapper({ children }: TransitionWrapperProps) {
  const isFirstMount = useIsFirstMount();

  return (
    <div className={`transition-bg ${isFirstMount ? '' : 'bg-changed'}`}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}



For example i can use it inside the layout.tsx file :


return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <TransitionWrapper>{children}</TransitionWrapper>
      </body>
    </html>
  );



After this one you can try to create some routes and try this out. By the way i added these styles but you can try more :


.transition-bg {
  transition: background-color 1.5s ease;
}

.bg-changed {
  background-color: blue;
}



